# Can I safely uninstall JavaFX and still use JRE 7?

Tags: windows, java

I finally got around to updating to JRE 7 today, and noticed that it came bundled with JavaFX 2.

I'm generally attentive during installation processes to ensure that I don't leave any check-boxes marked for software I don't want bundled.  However, this somehow still ended up as part of the package.

Is JavaFX a requirement for JRE now?  Can I uninstall JavaFX without affecting JRE?  Is there a way to download JRE without having JavaFX bundled?

OS is Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, JavaFX is not yet a required part of the JRE, though it is bundled with them, and so it should be uninstallable.

Starting with Java 8, however, JavaFX will become a part of the JRE/JDK, and will be necessary to have a compliant installation. The intention is for JavaFX to replace the Swing windowing library that currently exists in the JRE.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Any idea on how I can get a non-bundled copy of JRE?

Comment: See here for a list of non-essential (javafx) files that can be removed from your JRE installation http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html